# pyinstaller does not import modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, pyinstaller

When trying to compile my scripts with pyinstaller, In warning txt file I get this:

```
missing module named org - imported by copy missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle 
missing module named _subprocess - imported by subprocess 
missing module named msvcrt - imported by subprocess 
missing module named riscosenviron - imported by os 
missing module named riscospath - imported by os 
missing module named riscos - imported by os 
missing module named ce - imported by os 
missing module named _emx_link - imported by os 
missing module named os2 - imported by os 
missing module named nt - imported by os, ntpath 
missing module named 'widgets.icons' - imported by /home/user/dev/imageConverter/imageConverterWindow.py 
missing module named widgets - imported by /home/user/dev/imageConverter/imageConverterWindow.py 
missing module named checkFiles - imported by /home/user/dev/imageConverter/imageConverterWindow.py 
missing module named settings - imported by /home/user/dev/imageConverter/imageConverterWindow.py 
missing module named converter - imported by /home/user/dev/imageConverter/imageConverterWindow.py
```

As you can see there are bunch of modules pyinstaller does not see, including python modules. I'm Using Centos 7 and python 2.7.

Edit:
Simply re-installation worked.

Answer (score 0):

Simple re-installation worked.